# Scala for comprehension - tackling null

Tags: scala

In the snippet below:

```
 for {
  strVal  <- str
  longVal <- str.strToLong
 } yield longVal
```

where str is an Option[String]. What if str comes in as Some(null)? How to handle that in my for comprehension?

Comment: Well, how do you want to handle it? What do you want to happen when `str` is `Some(null)`?

Comment: I guess you meant:
`for {
  strVal  <- str;
  longVal <- strVal.strToLong
 } yield longVal` You can use:
`strValNullable  <- str;
  strVal <- Option(strValNullable);
  longVal <- strVal.strToLong`

Comment: I think the simple answer is "don't do that". The whole point of `Option` is to avoid the need for null. If you are using Java libraries that may return null, then sanitise values as soon as possible using the `Option()` apply constructor, which converts `null` to `None`

Comment: See also the [obligatory Some/None/null cartoon](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2013/04/20/this-week-in-scala-19042013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are dealing with `Some(null)` because you used that constructor in your code. 
Try `Option(variableWithNull)` and the result will be a `None`. Then all the operations with `None` will have a result of `None` instead of the annoying `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Perhaps you could use this code:

```
val str: Option[String] = Option(null)
str.fold(0L) {_.toLong}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Some(null)` should be an indicator that the upstream code is doing something wrong. Generally when wrapping something that could return null in an `Option` type, the `Option` apply should be used, as `Option(null)` evaluates to `None`.

If however you have no ability to influence that, you can always `flatMap` it to a `None`:

```
str.flatMap(Option(_))
```